# Node.js multiple config file for SQL Server database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, flutter

I have a web service that I wrote with Node.js. I am using this web service to provide connection between Flutter and SQL Server database. I have 3 databases with identical tables that perform the same function. So I want to connect to user selected database from a single web service. My `dbConfig.js` file is as follows:

```
const dbOmsGuvenlikConfig = {
    user: '*******',
    password: '*******',
    server: '********',
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    },
    database: '*******',
};

const dbOnlineBekciConfig = {
    user: '*******',
    password: '********',
    server: '*******',
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    },
    database: '******',
};

const dbOnlineMesaiConfig = {
    user: '********',
    password: '*******',
    server: '*******',
    options: {
        encrypt: false,
        trustServerCertificate: true,
    },
    database: '*******',
};

const config = {
    dbOnlineMesai: dbOnlineMesaiConfig,
    dbOnlineBekci: dbOnlineBekciConfig,
    dbOmsGuvenlik: dbOmsGuvenlikConfig,
};

module.exports = config;
```

My `login.js` file looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
const router = express.Router();

const dbConnection = (selectedDB) => {
    const dbConfig = require(`./databases/dbConfig.${selectedDB}`);
    return new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
}

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
   const selectedDB = req.query.selectedDB;

   const connection = dbConnection(selectedDB);

try {
    await connection.connect();

    const userName = req.query.userName;
    const password = req.query.password;

    const query = `SELECT * FROM KULLANICI WHERE KULLANICIADI = '${userName}' AND 
     SIFRE = '${password}'`;
    const result = await connection.request().query(query);

    const data = JSON.stringify(result.recordset);

    connection.close();
    res.send(data);
    } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(err);
    }
   });

   module.exports = router;
```

But when I try to connect, I get the following error.

```
(node:77823) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 
'./databases/dbConfig.dbOnlineBekci'
Require stack:
 - /home/business/myapp/routes/login.js
 - /home/business/myapp/app.js
 - /home/business/myapp/bin/www
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
at dbConnection (/home/business/myapp/routes/login.js:7:22)
at /home/business/myapp/routes/login.js:15:30
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/business/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/business/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (/home/business/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/business/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
   (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
 (node:77823) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This 
 error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch 
 block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate 
 the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled- 
 rejections=strict` (see 
 https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
 (node:77823) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
 deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate 
 the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: english maybe .....?

Comment: the error is telling you the issue, the problem is here const dbConfig = require(`./databases/dbConfig.${selectedDB}`); . i'm not sure what you actually wanna require but whatever it is, it can't find it

Comment: I'm getting the selectedDB part from the client. The ( . /databases/dbConfig.${selectedDB} ) part will look like this. ( . /databases/dbConfig.${dbOnlineBekci} ). But as I said, I'm getting an error. I couldn't understand why.

Comment: The `dbConfig.js` file only exports `config` and the things you are looking for are properties on that object. Have you tried rearranging your `require`/`use` statements to accomodate this?